# How to prevent ubuntu update firmware?

Tags: 18.04, alienware

Currently, I am using Alienware 17 R4 running ubuntu 18.04. In the past, I used to meet someone who broke his Alienware's motherboard by updating its firmware. By now, I still could not know the secured way to disable firmware updates whenever I run an update and upgrade command? any suggestion? thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're after (language has me a little confused; "*other broken the alienware*"??  but `apt-mark hold` can be used to place a hold on packages if absolutely necessary (can create issues down the road if forgotten it's there, or cause security concerns by using unpatched...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: @karel I am not sure which package that updates the firmware laptop.

Comment: 1. *amd64-microcode*  Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs 2. *intel-microcode* Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs

Comment: @guiverc I updated the question, sorry about that.

Comment: @karel so is there any other package that prevents not to update the bios, esp motherboard firmware? because that guy broke his motherboard caused by updating the os. I scared

Comment: 1. *iucode-tool* Intel processor microcode tool 2. *microcode.ctl* Intel IA32/IA64 CPU Microcode Utility (transitional package) The motherboard firmware update files are usually closed source and usually they must be run from Windows OS.

Comment: @karel thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `fwupd` to disabe this feature with:
`sudo apt remove fwupd`